# Delete zero values with prefix

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written a function that clears all zero values... What do I have to do, so that all 0 with + and - are also deleted? At the moment only +0 are deleted. What do I have to add in my RegEx?

My code:

```
  // Transform values
  public transformAmount(val: number) {
    // console.log('Value', val, val.toLocaleString('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 }));
    return val.toLocaleString('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 }).replace(/^-0+/, '');
  }
```

Comment: please show how the input looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I surely doubt if `/^-0+/` would work for `+0` since that regex indicate the beginning of the string should be `-` so it will only work with `-0`.

So if you want to replace `+0` and `-0` you can use this one:

```
/^[-+]?[0]$/g
```

Where `^` indicates the asserts position at the start of the string and `[]` indicate match characters present in it, then

Answer (score 1):

You assume that your string begins with `-0` that may be not true. Since we don't know your input there is regex for all `0`, `-0` and `+0` in your text.

```
.replace(/((-|\+)?0)/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

try the next regular expression, it removes all of them.

```js
.replace(/^[-0+]+/, '');

"+-0A" // will be "A"
"+-0+-A" // will be "A"
"A+-0+-" // will be "A+-0+-"
```

If you need only to remove only
`0`
`+0`
`-0`
Then use

```js
.replace(/^[-+]?0/, '');
```

If only
`+0`
`-0`
then use

```js
.replace(/^[-+]0/, '');
```

if anywhere, simply remove the leading `^` and add the `g` modifier.

```js
.replace(/[-+]0\b/g, ''); // \b - says word border, so +0123 will stay.
```